# Countif Reference Partial Cell

Tags: excel, formula

I am using Countif to count the amount of dates in another sheet using criteria to match another cell (the date listed next to the formula).

So in the sheet "Table1" I have a giant table with employees who are absent on certain dates, and I'm trying to tally their absencies in the whole sheet. The sheet is inconsistent since it is generated off a program then converted to an XML.

Currently I have to type in the date and the formula works, but when I try to reference the date next to it with wildcards, it's always 0.

```
=COUNTIF('Table 1'!$A$1:$R$7289,"*"&A7&"*")
```

That always returns 0.

```
=COUNTIF('Table 1'!$A$1:$R$7289,"*8/22/2016*")
```

This is correct, but I have to continue changing the date to match the date to the left.

Or is there any way to copy and paste this formula so the date automatically steps up 1?

Comment: Try `Text(A7,"m/d/yyyy")` in place of the `A7`

Comment: Bonus for sample data **without** an ambiguous MDY vs. DMY date.

Comment: ... or `=COUNTIF('Table 1'!$A$1:$R$7289, TEXT(A7, "\*m/d/yyyy\*"))`

Comment: @Jeeped  Where do you see his sample data?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld = In the formula as `"*8/22/2016*"`.

Comment: Need to see a sample of your actual data, and the actual contents of A7, to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: @Jeeped Are you assuming the asterisks are real characters then?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - No, I'm assuming that there are strings in 'Table 1'!$A$1:$R$7289 that *may* contain the string literal `8/22/2016` and that needs to be bracketed in wildcard characters to attain a wildcard count. fwiw, the formula I provided works for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139283/discussion-between-ron-rosenfeld-and-jeeped).

Answer (score 0):

```
=COUNTIF('Table 1'!$A$1:$R$7289, TEXT(A7, "\*m/d/yyyy\*"))
```

Worked perfectly, thank you!